# How do I stop Outlook from automatically attempting to open encrypted emails?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, encryption

I receive encrypted emails often enough that this has become an issue.

When I have encrypted emails in my inbox, using the arrow keys to navigate my inbox or even just opening outlook causes outlook to prompt me for my credentials to decrypt the email. It does this because outlook is trying to show me the email in the reading pane. This is extraordinarily inconvenient given my certs are on a smart card, so I must stop, insert my card, and complete the process, else outlook prompts me several times for my credentials, even if I try to cancel. Occasionally I even click away from the windows security smartcard window without noticing it, which freezes the reading pane entirely until my credentials are entered or I close the windows security smartcard window.

Without disabling the reading pane entirely, **is there a way to stop outlook from prompting me for my credentials while I am simply scrolling past an encrypted email?** I am happy to take extra steps to see an encrypted email, I just want the inconvenience of continual prompting to be gone.

Answer (score 1):

I have a very similar problem. Unfortunately, as far as I've been able to learn, your best option is indeed to disable the Reading Pane.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can add a registry variable to disable encrypted emails from being auto decrypted for the previews:
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\office\16.0\outlook\Security\DisableEncryptedMessagePreview`

This is a REG_DWORD key and you want to set the value to 1 to prevent the auto decrypt popups. Note that on my installation, I also had to create the Security\ directory

Answer (score -1):

What is the encryption type for the message you receive? Is it encrypted by [Microsoft 365 Message Encryption](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/encrypt-email-messages-373339cb-bf1a-4509-b296-802a39d801dc#:%7E:text=Encrypt%20with-,Microsoft%20365%20Message%20Encryption,-If%20you%20are)？

If so, based on my test on my Outlook 365 client, when I select an encrypted message in the message list, it cannot be previewed, and the reading pane displays as the below figure. And i will only be prompted for credentials when I double-click the encrypted information.
[image]

Of course, there is another case where you will be prompted to enter your credentials as soon as you open outlook. If you have enabled always restore previous items after starting outlook and you do turn off outlook when you open encrypted messages, the next time you start outlook, the open encrypted messages will be restored and you need to enter your credentials. If this is your case, please make sure to close encrypted messages before closing outlook.

Comment: The user specifically indicated they are using Outlook.  The message you are asking about (unclear why that part of your answer wasn't a comment), is a message that would only appear within OWA. You should [edit] your answer to specifically address the author's question.

Comment: The other has indicated they are using a Smart Card this implies they are using **S/MIME** to encrypt the emails.  Why are you using what type of encryption they are using within your own answer instead of a comment? This answer still does not address the author's root question.

Comment: You are not actually pinging that individual. You can only ping someone if they submitted a comment. So please stop asking. I am the only person being pinged. This is the second time I had to flag a comment like that